# Setting contentInset in storyboard

Tags: uitableview, ios7

I'm trying to add bottom and top inset in a UITableView. I add the values to the Storyboard or using this line:

```
    [tview setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(64, 0, 0, 0)];
```

... but I got a strange behaviour:

- If I touch the second row in the superior part, the first row gets selected

It seems that the elements are touchable area is getting the TOP contentInset, but the visual elements have an offset. See image:

[image]

I want to reproduce this exact behaviour:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/CreatingBasicScrollViews/CreatingBasicScrollViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008179-CH101-SW7

This was working fine in XCode5-DP4... when I upgraded to DP5 everything stopped working.

Ideas? Fixes?

Comment: It's best to ask this on the developer forums.  Because iOS 7 is still under NDA the chances of you getting an answer on here is slim.

Comment: @MattS. I've tried. I looked there for a week, posted the same question with no luck or even responses.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Even so, iOS 7 is still under NDA, so it's not appropriate to ask here. Check the latest iOS 7 and Xcode release notes to see if there's anything that might hint that something is broken in the latest release? I'm grasping at straws there, though.